# Where should I store my API key in IOS app

Tags: ios, swift

In Android I used to store my keys using NDK, what is the equivalent way of storing API keys in iOS. Can I store them in a header file?

Comment: Create a constants file and you can store keys into it.struct Appkeys {
    static let APP_DEVICE_ID = "Your device ID"
}

Comment: @manishsharma93 I am little bit new to iOS app development.. will the Constants.swift file safe to decompilation of my app

Comment: Yes. But if your data is too sensitive. Store it in Keychain. But remember you can't store much in it. Just few items.

Comment: @manishsharma93 But I think we cannot store a static value in keychain before app installs i.e. on first open I have to programatically add the API keys to the keychain?

Comment: Yes. Then go for constant file with Static.

Comment: @manishsharma93 Ok... cool